# XSL duplicate parent element for each occurance of child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to duplicate a parent element for each instance of a child element but I don't want to include the siblings of the child element in the output. 
I would then like to sort the parents based on a field in the child node

Sample input:

```
<Customer>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <Market>
    <MarketNumber>100</MarketNumber>
  </Market>
  <Market>
    <MarketNumber>200</MarketNumber>
  </Market>
  <c/>
</Customer>
<Customer>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <Market>
    <MarketNumber>100</MarketNumber>
  </Market>
  <c/>
</Customer>
```

Desired output (3 customer with one market each):

```
<Customer>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <Market>
    <MarketNumber>100</MarketNumber>
  </Market>
  <c/>
</Customer>
<Customer>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <Market>
    <MarketNumber>100</MarketNumber>
  </Market>
  <c/>
</Customer>
<Customer>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <Market>
    <MarketNumber>200</MarketNumber>
  </Market>
  <c/>
</Customer>
```

I have solved it by selecting all markets and copying its parent elements manually but would like to do it without naming them (its 33 elements in the parent node). The problem is I can't select "../." because then i also copy the sibling market.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Customer/Market">
    <xsl:sort select="MarketNumber" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
...
<xsl:template match="Market">
    <!--Duplicate all customer data for each market-->
    <Customer>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../a"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../b"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/> <!--Current market -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="../c"/>
    </Customer>
</xsl:template>
```

I suspect this can be solved by copying parent element except Market and then copy Market with "." like i do above but I cant figure out how to.. Any hints welcome! Other solutions welcome as well but it needs to handle the sorting too.

Thanks!
Richard

Comment: "I have solved it by selecting all markets and copying its parent elements manually" -- do you mean copying its *sibling* elements manually? Otherwise, I don't understand how that relates to the XSLT you showed.

Comment: Also, it makes a difference whether you have XSLT 2.0 available or are stuck with 1.0. Which are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Customer/Market">
    <xsl:sort select="MarketNumber" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
...
<xsl:template match="Market">
    <!--Duplicate all customer data for each market-->
    <Customer>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::Market)] | ."/>
    </Customer>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy all siblings that are not `Market` elements, and will also copy the current (matched) `Market` element. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you Lars! It works as expected and I can change element names or add new elements without needing to update the XSL.

Comment: @RichardL: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer (click the checkmark) if this solved your problem.

Comment: Ah thanks, tried to upvote it but I had too low reputation.. didn't see the checkmark until now :)

Comment: I have a different mapping that is slightly more complex in that the Market number is nested one level deeper like this '<Customer><x/><Markets><Market>200</Market><Market>101</Market></Markets><y/></Customer>'. I still want only one Market per Customer but if i adapt your example with '<xsl:copy-of select="../../*[not(self::Markets/Market)] | ../."/>' I get two customers but with both markets on them

Comment: @RichardL: You might have to post a new question for that one. The solution is sufficiently more complicated, and I don't think I have time to work it up in the next few hours (wish I did!) P.S. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a few years late to the party, but just had this requirement myself.  The solution I came up with was to use named templates to recursively copy the XML tree, excluding element names which I didn't want copied, and using the `generate-id` function to identify the node which I still wanted to be copied.  See comments in the below code for more detail.

This solution works in XSLT 1.0.

An XSLT Fiddle example is available here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWm.

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- copy everything as is, unless told otherwise-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- 
  match on the document element
  ensure there's a single root element, Customers
  match on any Market nodes, so we get a copy of everything for that Market's customer (as per the Market template) with that Market
  OR match any customer that doesn't have any markets; so we don't exclude those from the results (did you want that; if not switch the apply-templates for the commented out version below)
  -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Customers>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Market|//Customer[not(./Markets/Market)]" />
      <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="//Market" /> -->
    </Customers>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- 
  For the markets matched above, call our copyAllButMe template
  set the rootNode (the node to be copied) to the current Market's ancestor Customer element
  set the ignoreElementName to the current element's name (i.e. so when copying the customer, we don't copy any child Market elements
  set the includeNodeId to the current element's id (i.e. so when ignoring other Markets, we don't ignore the current element)
  -->
  <xsl:template match="Market">
    <xsl:call-template name="copyAllButMe">
      <xsl:with-param name="rootNode" select="../.." />
      <xsl:with-param name="ignoreElementName" select="local-name()" />
      <xsl:with-param name="includeNodeId" select="generate-id()" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--
  Test: 
    Is the current element's name a name we should be ignoring?  
    If it is, does this element's ID match the ID we want to include?
  If we're not ignoring this element name, or the id is the one to include then we proceed:
  Copy the element's name
  Copy any attrinbutes of thie element
  Loop through all child nodes of this element
  - If the child node is itself an element, call this template (i.e. recursion)
  - Otherwise (e.g. it' text node, comment node, etc), copy the node as-is
  -->
  <xsl:template name="copyAllButMe">
    <xsl:param name="rootNode" />
    <xsl:param name="ignoreElementName" />
    <xsl:param name="includeNodeId" />
    <xsl:if test="(local-name($rootNode) != $ignoreElementName) or (generate-id($rootNode) = $includeNodeId)">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name($rootNode)}" namespace="{namespace-uri($rootNode)}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$rootNode/attribute::*" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$rootNode/child::node()">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::*">
              <xsl:call-template name="copyAllButMe">
                <xsl:with-param name="rootNode" select="self::node()" />
                <xsl:with-param name="ignoreElementName" select="$ignoreElementName" />
                <xsl:with-param name="includeNodeId" select="$includeNodeId" />
              </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```